# Automatically saving in a batch action

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, automation, save

I have an action in Photoshop:

1. Set Background
2. Black & White
3. Make adjustment layer
4. Set Current adjustment layer

Then I go to `File->Automate->Batch` and set it to output to a folder with Override action 'save as' commands unchecked (though tried with it checked) and File Naming as photo + 2 Digit Serial Number + extension.

When I run it, it prompts me with a save-as dialog box with every file, which defeats a good chunk of the whole purpose.  Am I missing a setting to have it automatically save these images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add "Save As" to the action. And "Close" as well, unless you want them to remain open. "Override Save As" only overrides the destination. If you don't have Save As as part of the action, there's nothing to override.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your action then click on begin recording and then add save as and close in action and then click on stop recarding now this work fine for you..

i think save for web better option is becauase when you image save as image it's goes on older location of image where original image restore but when you save for web it always go on new location.

Answer (score 0):

please consider my attachment below.

my action applies "auto color" + "auto contrast + " auto tone"
then saves the file
then closes the file

hopefully this could help someone

-

[image: save file and close in photoshop cs6]